# Tag template for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have setup a Custom Post Type called 'Sports Clubs'. These use tags.
I need a page to display a list of posts associated with the various tags.

I'm currently doing this for standard posts via the template 'tag.php'.
An example URL is [www.website.com/tag/tag-name/](http://www.website.com/tag/tag-name/)
This works great for standard posts. But its not working for the custom post types. I would assume the output page would be something like [www.website.com/sports-clubs/tag-name/](http://www.website.com/sports-clubs/tag-name/)

I've tried adding templates 'tag-sports-clubs.php' and 'taxonomy-sports-clubs_tag.php' with no joy.
The tags strangely link to my index.php page which is being used for search results.

Comment: take a look at `pre_get_posts` to change the value of the `post_type` parameter on the main query for that archive. There's no special version of the tag archive/URL/template just for that CPT

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error I found a solution.
I needed to create a template called 'taxonomy-sports-clubs.php'. This contains a loop listing all the posts for specific tags.